# Getting the text within an input box

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the text within an input box and go to the page ending with it? For example, if someone types "home" in an input box it directs the user to the URL https://mysitename.com/home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `document.location.href`.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('button');
let ipt = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');

btn.onclick = function() {
  document.location.href = "https://mysitename.com/" + ipt.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="link name">
<button>go</button>
```

Comment: Okay! I'll try that. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

You can check this solution. This will append the `input value` to your current `host name`.

If you want predefined hostName then your can set the value to this variable. `const hostName = "your host name here"`

You can use `window.location.href = yourNewUrl` to redirect to new address. I've commented out the redirection line. You need to uncomment that.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#myForm');
const inputField = document.querySelector('#name');


form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);

function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const pageName = inputField.value;
  inputField.value = '';
  const hostName = window.location.hostname;
  
  const url = `${hostName}/${pageName}`;
  console.log(url);
  
//   window.location.href = url;

}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="type name and hit enter">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 0):

**Simply**  type and direct to that link

by `.addEventListener` event change as you wish,

```js
var mySearchInput = document.getElementById('mySearchInput');

mySearchInput.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
  document.location.href = "https://mysitename.com/" + mySearchInput.value;
})
```

```html
<label>Link</label>
<input type="text" id="mytext" placeholder="Type link here..." />
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond!